# php cron job file upload to ftp

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp, cron

I am using php script to upload file on some ftp server. When I start my script through browser it is working fine, but when the script is running as cron job script doesn't upload file on my ftp server. 
What are the differences between running script from browsers and as cron job?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try running the php script from command line manually? Did you check the error log?

Comment: php cli, vs php through Apache, quite a few differences. but with out seeing your code .. who knows

Comment: cron and Apache will have different working directories, different shell environments (PATH in particular), different user IDs (aka permissions)... they're quite different, and just because it works in one environment means absolutely nothing to the other.

Comment: Thanks for a fast response. Problem is I do not have any access to server where cron is running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the web version works and cron situation is too convoluted, you could try one of these variants for the cron job:

`lynx --source "http://some.host/myfile.php?some=option" > /dev/null`

Alternatively, you could use links, curl or even wget.

Answer (score 1):

When you are running from the browser you are running as whatever user Apache is running as. When you are running from crontab you are running as whatever user you setup the cron under.  It sounds likely that you have a permissions issue.